# What are some pro's and con's of virtualizing a MongoDB config server?

Tags: virtualization, mongodb

We are setting up a new MongoDB cluster for a large web app, and trying to decide what our infrastructure will look like.

I am researching whether or not we could virtualize the MongoDB Config server or if it should be run on "real" hardware.

Can you give some potential pro's and con's (specific to MongoDB config servers if possible)  of each, and recommendations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use VMs for your config servers, but I would take care that you keep them on separate host servers from one another.  Also, be sure to take care to size their RAM appropriately; They should not be RAM-starved.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, MongoDB config servers can be virtualized. See [MongoDB on Amazon EC2](http://www.10gen.com/webinars/ec2), where 10gen actually recommends using micro instances on EC2 (which IIRC, only give you ~600MB of memory). Config servers do not need much in the way of system resources, so physical machines are almost definitely overkill.